# Problem with accept() function What if I have more than MAX_INT clients?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, networking

The `accept()` or `accept4()` function returns an integer but if I received more than `INT_MAX` clients connections, what will happen?

Comment: You should have long-since had to distribute the system to balance the load.

Comment: @user4581301 Do you mean I will do a casting like this   long new_sock = (long)accept() ?

Comment: Casting doesn't magically make a function return a larger type. Are you truly concerned about having 2.1 billion active connections?

Comment: socket `fd`s are recycled, if that helps at all.

Comment: What I mean is long before it reaches 2 billion active connections any one computer would have run out of at least one other resource.

Comment: @RetiredNinja yes i want to serve 7 billion clients

Comment: You aren't doing that with one computer, at least not in the next several generations of computer architectures. Google has server farms the size of colosseums scattered around the world serving a fraction of that load.

Comment: 7 billion simultaneously. I suppose it's good to have goals.

Comment: Business must be booming!

Answer (score 8):

> What will happen??

The `accept` call will fail. It will however most likely fail long before you reach `INT_MAX` with something like `EMFILE` *"The per-process limit on the number of open file descriptors has been reached."* in Linux.

In reality, this will unlikely happen. When you've closed a socket, the used file descriptor is available for re-use again - and you are not likely going to attempt to serve ~2.1 billion clients at the same time on a single computer.

Comment: Yes, here's hoping :)

Comment: Oh, but for the good old days when you had 50 file handles. Period. Computers were so much simpler then. Playing Jumpman, maybe Wing Commander.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but if i want  to serve more than 2 billion connections What's the solution?

Comment: @john  You're welcome! You'd need a larger server park for that and share the load between all the servers.

Comment: @user4581301 Ah, the Wing Commander days. Hours spent optimizing config.sys and autoexec.bat to squeeze out a few more k of main memory, :)